# Is there a way to connect a custom post type to another custom post type's taxonomy? (specific to locations)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Curious to know if anyone can provide a solution to the following...

I have 2 custom post types:

1. Offers

   - Location (taxonomy)
2. Businesses

   - Location (taxonomy)

I want to sort both offers and businesses by location but don't want to have to duplicate all the locations or add a new location to both custom post types. Is there a way for me to LINK the Businesses custom post type to the "Offers Location" taxonomy? I ask this because I don't want to have duplicated locations, unless this is not possible to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know that I can register a taxonomy for more than 1 CPT/post type!

```
    register_taxonomy( 'location', array( 'offer', 'store' ), array(
        'label' => __( 'Location', 'themeify' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name'                          => __( 'Location', 'themeify' ),
            'singular_name'                 => __( 'Location', 'themeify' ),
            'menu_name'                     => __( 'Location', 'themeify' ),
            'all_items'                     => __( 'All Locations', 'themeify' ),
            'edit_item'                     => __( 'Edit Location', 'themeify' ),
            'view_item'                     => __( 'View Location', 'themeify' ),
            'update_item'                   => __( 'Update Location', 'themeify' ),
            'add_new_item'                  => __( 'Add New Location', 'themeify' ),
            'new_item_name'                 => __( 'New Location Name', 'themeify' ),
            'parent_item'                   => __( 'Parent Location', 'themeify' ),
            'parent_item_colon'             => __( 'Parent Location:', 'themeify' ),
            'search_items'                  => __( 'Search Locations', 'themeify' ),
            'popular_items'                 => __( 'Popular Locations', 'themeify' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas'    => __( 'Separate locations with commas', 'themeify' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'           => __( 'Add or remove locations', 'themeify' ),
            'choose_from_most_used'         => __( 'Choose from the most used locations', 'themeify' ),
            'not_found'                     => __( 'No locations found', 'themeify' ),
        )

    ) );
```

I added the array with the custom post type 'offer' and 'store'.

Now, when I add a location to this taxonomy, it updates within BOTH offers and store :) No duplication of locations :D